# How to monitor GuideWire application with GW inbuilt monitoring tool?

Tags: performance, monitoring, loadrunner, vugen, guidewire

We are doing performance testing of guidewire application,related batch process and REST API. We have a requirement to monitor batch processes and REST API performance with Guidewire monitoring tool. I am new to this. Can someone suggest how to monitor this and get performance statistics from GW inbuilt monitoring tool.

Comment: Hi. Which version?

Comment: I don't know which you asked, but here is the what i get from application :  

**Application Version**: 10.0.3.1230  

**Platform Version**: 10.13.7  

**Schema Version**: 301  

**Customer Version**: 1.0.0-147

Comment: Why can you not use the built in monitoring capability of LoadRunner, including the ability to use a custom virtual user to monitor a console with batch status, correlating for information off of the console, then converting those items to datapoints for use in analysis?

Comment: We are sending data to MQ we don't get any response from that... But in backend it calls various batch process and rest API, which are in guidewire application. So basically wanted to know how to use guidewire in built monitor tool to get the statistics of those batch processes and rest API's